# How to scale image and center it on a UIButton in Swift?

Tags: swift, uibutton

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
var image = UIImage(named: "myimage.png") as UIImage!
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
```

I have an image that I've set on my button, but I'd like to scale it to be smaller than the button (for example the image should be 50,50) and center in the button. How might I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Xcode 8.3.1 • Swift 3.1**

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
let image = UIImage(named: "myimage.png")

func buttonTouchDown(_ button: UIButton) {
    print("button Touch Down")
}
```

---

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0 , width: 100, height: 100)
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTouchDown), for: .touchDown)
    button.setTitle("Title", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(25,25,25,25)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: `UIButton.imageEdgeInsets` is deprecated in IOS 15

Answer (score 12):

Swift 5, Swift 4, Swift 3

```
var image = UIImage(named: "myimage") as UIImage!   
btnetc.setImage(image, for: .normal)
btnetc.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

or

```
btnetc.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

or

```
btnetc.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

Comment: How does this change the size of the button image to 50x50?

Comment: just resize your button its will automatically change the height and width

Comment: The button should be 100x100 and the image 50x50, I don't understand how your solution handle this?

Comment: you can just get the button inner image view and redraw the size what ever you want your problem will be solved

Comment: For photos, use scaleAspectFit

Answer (score 10):

Ther is a much easier way to do this where you don't have to deal with content insets. Here its is:

```
var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
var image = UIImage(named: "myimage.png") as UIImage!
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
button.setImage(image, forState: .Normal)
button.contentMode = .center
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 7):

Or via `XIB` after selecting your `UIButton`.

*Just make sure your insets are all the same.*

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Xcode 13, Swift 5

Using storyboard, select the button, then in the size inspect click the dropdown on size just above Content inset. There is a list of sizes to select from, and this will adjust your image size(if you use system image). The default size is already set when you added the button on the storyboard to the View Controller.